# Parallel execution of "Building" and "Load Target Platform"

Tags: eclipse

I am working with a huge workspace (~1200 bundles/fragments) and a target platform (file) with about ~800 additional bundles. Settting up this workspace (switch branch, change target platform, etc.) and make it "green" takes a lot of time (20min-2hrs). During setting up this workspace I realized that some of the Eclipse internal tasks such as "Building" and "Loading Target PLatform" are executed in parallel.

[image: Screenshot of my progress view]

But this doesn't make much sense to me, because I assume you cannot successfully build the workspace unless all required plug-in dependencies are resolved. This implies loading the target platform should be done in prior to building the actual workspace. The result is, that once "Building" and "Load TP" is finished, the workspace is a mess with >100000 errors and it requires some hardcore "[Eclipse Dance](http://underlap.blogspot.com/2011/10/eclipse-dance-steps.html)"[tm] to make it "green".

My question is:

Could some sort of exclusion between those task solve this problem?
Is there a way to specify some sort of rules between those tasks from within the Eclipse IDE itself?
In case its only possible by manipulating the underlying Eclipse.org java classes, which one would that be and what would be a recommended way to do so?

Comment: Make sure your Eclipse is up to date and show what you have configured in the preferences _General > Workspace > Build_. Avoid cyclic dependencies between projects, as a change in a dependent project triggers a rebuild.

Comment: Background Jobs can set rules to stop conflicting jobs from running at the same time, many jobs already do this. What they use can only be changed by updating the source code and rebuilding the plug-in.

Comment: you let the bounty expire and then accepted the answer so the bounty was not awarded to @howgler. I note for me not to answer any of your future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **parallel building of projects** can be enable in the **preferences** in ***General > Workspace > Build*** by setting ***Max simultaneous project builds*** to **2 or higher**.

Please note that such slow building of projects as you describe is probably caused by something else:

1. **Make sure your Eclipse** (the platform and all plugins) **is up to date**. According to the screenshot, your Eclipse seems pretty old, so you will miss the [numerous performance improvements that have been made in recent versions](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/showdependencytree.cgi?id=571430&hide_resolved=0). For example, [since EGit 5.6 only files actually modified instead of all files are refreshed](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.6#Performance_Improvements) when switching to a different branch.
2. **Make sure** it is **not caused by a plugin** you have installed. Some plugins can dramatically slow down building of projects, even when not used. So check it, whether you can reproduce it with an Eclipse without additional plugin.
3. **Avoid circular dependencies** since they can cause multiple build iteration (a project that has been changed triggers a build in the projects that depend on the project; which can result in a change that in turn can trigger the building of more projects; and so on): in ***Project > Properties: Java Compiler > Build*** set ***Circular dependencies*** to ***Error*** (which is the default).
4. **Avoid project builder cycles**. A project can have multiple builders (see *Project > Properties: Builders*). All builders will be executed until no file is changed. Touching a file without changing its contents is also a change. For Maven project, you can use the ***Maven Workspace Build* view** to debug this.

Comment: Thanks @howlger 
The screenshot was taken from a 2020-06. But I use the old look'n'feel. But you are right, we have to keep our custom eclipse up-to-date (I am actually in the middle to update to 2021-09).
I think the main reason is the fact that we have a ton of circular dependencies due to test fragments and their extra dependencies (such as "utility bundles").
We have "parallel builds" set to four. That was the recommendation I took from a EclipseCon 2017.
But do you believe, that "updating target platform" and "Building workspace" can be executed in parallel, like in the screenshot?

Comment: @gia Updating the target platform will trigger a rebuild of the plugin projects (projects with "Plug-in Dependencies" and I guess also verifying of feature projects like in your screenshot). In your case, _Building_ should wait for _Load Target Platform_ instead of doing _Building_ twice (not sure, if this is already the case in the current version; otherwise this can be improved).

Answer (score 0):

For large projects I disable "Build automatically" in the "Project" menu before updating from source code repository and building it with Gradle/Maven. After Gradle finished I enable "Build automatically" back.